# Spring boot from scratch gives a whitelabel in browser: is it ok?

Tags: spring-boot

I check Spring boot project from start.spring.io

When I start IntelliJIDEA I get whitelabel message in browser by address http://localhost:8080/: This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Is it ok?

Structure of my project:
[image: Text]

My application.properties:

## MySQL properties

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin

## Hibernate properties

hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#Thymeleaf properties
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true

spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@

My pom.xml:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.0-M4
 

com.example
springbootdem
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
war
springbootdem
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

My run log:

C:\Users\admin.jdks\openjdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=56741:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\java\springbootdem\target\classes;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.0-M5\spring-aop-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.9.1\aspectjweaver-1.9.9.1.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.0.0-M5\spring-jdbc-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.1.1.Final\hibernate-core-6.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.0.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.12\byte-buddy-1.12.12.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\3.0.2\jaxb-runtime-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\3.0.2\jaxb-core-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\3.0.2\txw2-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.0.1\istack-commons-runtime-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.0\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.10\antlr4-runtime-4.10.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.0.0-M5\spring-data-jpa-3.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.0.0-M5\spring-data-commons-3.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.0.0-M5\spring-orm-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.0.0-M5\spring-context-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.0.0-M5\spring-tx-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.0.0-M5\spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.0.0-M5\spring-aspects-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-starter-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.18.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.18.0.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.18.0\log4j-api-2.18.0.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring6\3.1.0.M2\thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.1.0.M2\thymeleaf-3.1.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-starter-web-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-starter-json-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.3\jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.3\jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.3\jackson-core-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.0.0-M5\spring-web-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.0.0-M5\spring-webmvc-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.0.0-M5\spring-expression-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.29\mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.0.0-M4\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.0.0-M4.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.0.0\jakarta.annotation-api-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.0.22\tomcat-embed-core-10.0.22.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.0.22\tomcat-embed-el-10.0.22.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.0.22\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.0.22.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\3.0.1\jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\2.0.1\jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.0-M5\spring-core-6.0.0-M5.jar;C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.0.0-M5\spring-jcl-6.0.0-M5.jar com.example.springbootdem.SpringbootdemApplication

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::             (v3.0.0-M4)

2022-07-31T15:26:36.805+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.SpringbootdemApplication           : Starting SpringbootdemApplication using Java 18.0.1.1 on DESKTOP-AAKSGJM with PID 1700 (C:\java\springbootdem\target\classes started by admin in C:\java\springbootdem)
2022-07-31T15:26:36.810+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.SpringbootdemApplication           : The following 1 profile is active: "@spring.profiles.active@"
2022-07-31T15:26:36.929+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-07-31T15:26:36.929+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-07-31T15:26:38.046+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-31T15:26:38.074+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-07-31T15:26:39.132+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-07-31T15:26:39.157+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-31T15:26:39.157+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.22]
2022-07-31T15:26:39.288+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-31T15:26:39.289+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2358 ms
2022-07-31T15:26:39.582+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-07-31T15:26:40.573+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@10d967f8
2022-07-31T15:26:40.578+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-07-31T15:26:40.654+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-07-31T15:26:40.805+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.1.Final
2022-07-31T15:26:41.283+03:00  WARN 1700 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2022-07-31T15:26:41.720+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2022-07-31T15:26:42.197+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-07-31T15:26:42.212+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-31T15:26:42.295+03:00  WARN 1700 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-07-31T15:26:42.663+03:00  WARN 1700 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2022-07-31T15:26:42.804+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-07-31T15:26:42.864+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-07-31T15:26:42.877+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.SpringbootdemApplication           : Started SpringbootdemApplication in 6.829 seconds (process running for 8.4)
2022-07-31T15:29:28.139+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-31T15:29:28.213+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-31T15:29:28.770+03:00  INFO 1700 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 555 ms

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's ok.
One should add controller @RequestMapping - to point url for application.